# How to union and get overall sum of three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join, union-all

My query

```
     ------------------------------------------
     Select cat_name,cat,total
       From
          (
            SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
             Count (a.category_name) as cat,
                   Sum( b.position) as total
              FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.nsdl b
             WHERE a.bene_type_nsdl = b.bene_type 
               AND a.bene_stype_nsdl= b.bene_stype
               And b.date ='2016-07-22' 
          Group By cat_name
         UNION All
            SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
                   Count(a.category_name) as cat,
                     Sum( b.shares) as total
              FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.cdsl b
             WHERE a.type_cdsl = b.type
               AND a.bo_substat_cdsl= b.bo_substat
               And b.date ='2016-07-22' group by cat_name
         UNION All
            SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
                   Count(a.category_name) as cat,
                     Sum( b.shares) as total
             FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.member_member_master b
            WHERE a.substatus_phy = b.substatus
              And b.date ='2016-07-22' 
              And shares > '0' 
         Group By cat_name 
        ) 
       c Group By cat_name 
      ------------------------------------
```

Returns

```
     ----------------------------
       cat_name             cat       total
      Resident Individual   2705      2317048
     ---------------------------------------
```

if I run the three table separately I will get the output as

```
      ----------------------------------------
        cat_name             cat       total
      Resident Individual   2705      2317048
      Resident Individual    991      355218
      Resident Individual   3284      1219027
      ---------------------------------------
```

but I need the output as

```
       --------------------------
        cat_name                 cat       total
      Resident Individual        6980     3891293
      -----------------------------------
```

I am trying to get overall count of field name in the table but I am getting the answer of first table alone. Help me to find the solution.

Comment: mysql or oracle? Are you sure you posted the exact query you are running? The query you posted has 3 columns in select list, but only one in the group by

Answer (score 2):

The first line of your query change to

```
select cat_name, sum(cat) as cat, sum(total) as total
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
select cat_name,sum(cat) as cat,sum(total) as total
     from
     (SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
     count(a.category_name) as cat,
     sum( b.position) as total
     FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.nsdl b
     WHERE a.bene_type_nsdl = b.bene_type 
     AND 
     a.bene_stype_nsdl= b.bene_stype
     And
     b.date ='2016-07-22' group by cat_name
     UNION all
     SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
     count(a.category_name) as cat,
     sum( b.shares) as total
     FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.cdsl b
     WHERE a.type_cdsl = b.type
     AND 
     a.bo_substat_cdsl= b.bo_substat
     And
     b.date ='2016-07-22' group by cat_name
     UNION all
     SELECT a.category_name as cat_name,
     count(a.category_name) as cat,
     sum( b.shares) as total
     FROM erom.category a, erom_kmch.member_member_master b
     WHERE a.substatus_phy = b.substatus
    And
    b.date ='2016-07-22' And shares > '0' group by cat_name ) 
   c group by cat_name
```

You have to sum in main query also

Comment: Thank you so much mr.robinbansalsolutions, it's working